# Unsafe conversion to given pointer in buffer

Tags: c#

I am trying to figure out how to get this method to start at a index being ptr instead of overwriting from 0 - 8 bytes. Also if anyone knows how to make this work with Big / Little edian machines due to being networked, that would be awesome.

```
private byte[] buffer = new byte[30];
private int ptr = 0;

unsafe void GetBytes(ulong value)
{
    fixed (byte* b = buffer) //start at buffer[ptr]
        *((int*)b) = *(int*)&value;

    ptr += 8;
}
```

I figured out how to make a pointer to the ptr via the following

```
private byte[] buffer = new byte[30];
private int ptr = 0;

unsafe void GetBytes(ulong value)
{
    fixed (byte* b = &buffer[ptr]) //start at buffer[ptr]
        *((int*)b) = *(int*)&value;

    ptr += 8;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can convert endianness easily:

```
using System.Buffers.Binary;

if (!BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
{
    value = BinaryPrimitives.ReverseEndianness(value);
}
```

I would prefer to use `Span` which will be safer and easier to read:

```
using System.Buffers.Binary;

Span<byte> span = buffer;
BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt64LittleEndian(span.Slice(ptr), value);
```

If you want to use your system's endianness rather than something explicit, you can do that too:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

Span<byte> span = buffer;
MemoryMarshal.Write(span.Slice(ptr), value);
```

**Edit for non-Core:**

You can use [`HostToNetworkOrder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.ipaddress.hosttonetworkorder?view=netframework-4.5#System_Net_IPAddress_HostToNetworkOrder_System_Int64_) to convert integers to big endian prior to writing to your pointer.

Comment: I actually figured it out.. Going to change the comment but still wondering about endianness. Thing is I really need the solution to run as fast as possible right now with 10 million calls I am benchmarking at about 112ms.

Comment: See the `Span` option I gave for an endian-specific write.

Comment: Thank you for the above I up voted the answer, I can not use the solution though because I'm stuck using .net 4.5. Its not that I wouldn't love to change the framework version its a software limitation. Thank you for your time and efforts :)

Comment: Arg :). Okay, I added one more quick edit, hope that works for you.

Comment: I just seen the HostToNetworkOrder looks promising. Thank you again also the ms on the 10 million calls was incorrect its actually 0.0009 ms. Not sure why I put 112.